# asp.net validator control issue

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-controls

I have a validator that check an input.
i what that the validator displayed "valid" if the value is valid,
and "invalid" if the value is hasnt passed the validation.

can i manage this without adding an addional lable for the valid state(by setting the visibility: true/false)?

does the validator control has am alternative value, or i have to override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the validators are designed to render text if there was a validation error, and to be unobtrusive if not.

Of course, you could create a new Validator inheriting from `BaseValidator` that would do this.

There's [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304131838/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092006-1.aspx) giving a good overview of how to do this.